# Knife: command not found

Tags: chef-infra

I was trying to run **Knife ssl fetch** command in my workstation(I already downloaded unzip the ChefDk and installed on my workstation) but it was showing knife command not found.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say with any certainty as you have given no details of any kind, but this probably means you didn't install ChefDK correctly. You can check by looking for the install path, `/opt/chefdk` on most platforms.